# java.lang.IllegalStateException Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Hello I'm starting to learn building apps for Android. I'm using Retrofit to get a json response. This is the structure:

```
{"Results": [         
   {             
    "Id": 1,             
    "Feed": 1,             
    "Title": "title",
    "Summary": "Text",             
    "PublishDate": "2015-09-12T21:45:16",             
    "Image": "imageurl",
    "Url": "websiteurl",
    "Related": [                 
      "relatedurl",
      "relatedurl"
     ],             
    "Categories": [                 
       {                     
       "Id": 61,                     
       "Name": "Sport"                 
       },{                     
        "Id": 63,                     
        "Name": "Voetbal" 
            }              
        ],             
        "IsLiked": false         
       }     
    ],     
    "NextId": 4285 }
```

These are my models:

```
 public class Result {
  private String NextId;
  private Results[] Results;
 }

 public class Results {
  private String Url;
  private String Feed;
  private String Image;
  private String Id;
  private List<String> Related;
  private List<Categories> Categories;
  private String PublishDate;
  private String Title;
  private String IsLiked;
  private String Summary;
 }

 public class Categories {
  private String Name;
  private String Id;
 }
```

And my interface looks like this:

```
public interface WebService {
 @GET("articles")
 Call<List<Result>> Articles();
}
```

I got a fatal error during runtime:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was
>   BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

The endpoint returns a `JSONObject` but you are telling retrofit that is returning a `JSONArray`.

Change

```
Call<List<Result>> Articles();
```

with

```
Call<Result> Articles();
```

also `NextId` and `Id` in the `JSON` you posted are not `String`

Answer (score 1):

Add DTO Plugin in Android studio. **Data Transfer Object(DTO) generator that generates Java classes from the given feed.**

Here is your correct model class

```
{
    public static class Results {
        @SerializedName("Id")
        public int id;
        @SerializedName("Feed")
        public int feed;
        @SerializedName("Title")
        public String title;
        @SerializedName("Summary")
        public String summary;
        @SerializedName("PublishDate")
        public String publishdate;
        @SerializedName("Image")
        public String image;
        @SerializedName("Url")
        public String url;
        @SerializedName("Related")
        public List<Related> related;
        @SerializedName("Categories")
        public List<Categories> categories;
        @SerializedName("IsLiked")
        public boolean isliked;
    }

 public static class Categories {
        @SerializedName("Id")
        public int id;
        @SerializedName("Name")
        public String name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

id, feed and NextId are not string, you are fetching data with a wrong structure . And try with

```
Call<Result> Articles()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes

Your interface should be change to

```
public interface WebService {
 @GET("articles")
 Call<Result> Articles();
}
```

in your model class

```
public class Result {
  private String NextId;
  private List<Results> Results;
 }
```